# Error installing Python module 'cx_freeze'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to install the cx_freeze module in order to convert my current code into a standalone application. When downloading cx_freeze, I am getting this issue.

```
running build_ext
building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++
Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Is there anything I can do to work around installing this? I noticed some posts that say, you could install some wheels, but will that affect my project at all?

Comment: Download it and try again: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Affect your project in what way? See http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil what package?

Comment: cx_freeze of course - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze

Answer (score 1):

if You do not want to build cx_freeze, You may use precompiled binary wheel from this page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze . I think about that is easiest way to install cx_freeze on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install Microsoft Visual Studio C++ [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) then reboot your computer and try again!